# How to create a woo-commerce store were the user can't purchase an item without being accepted by the admin

Tags: wordpress, email, plugins, woocommerce, authentication

Summarized problem:

I'm setting up a woo commerce store where the customer has to ask for permission before creating an account on the store. How do I do that?

Provide background:

My client is selling products that require detailed instructions that only qualified people can use, at the moment anyone can create an account and buy a product. Is there a way the website can notify the client of registering customers before giving the customer access to the products? like an accept or reject email for new customer registrations?

Answer (score 1):

- Block the common ways to create an account;
- Create a condition that shows the "buy" button just for logged-in users;
- Add a form for the user to demonstrate their interest in having the access to buy the products, with the data that is needed to the approval;
- The admin check the submited form, and then creates the account with some "welcome" message.

This can be handled with some plugins, using the hooks from woocommerce and wordpress.
You could even create a new panel on Wp dashboard that sees the submited forms, with 2 buttons with "approve", "disapprove", and a field for feedback.

When approve is clicked, the plugin creates a new account and send to the user the feedback and instructions.
When disapprove is clicked, the plugin sends to the user the feedback message with "sorry" message.

This way would be less frustrating to the user, they wouldn't need the approval for every buy.

Some links to help you in this quest:

[Woocommerce hooks API Documentation](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html)

[Add dashboard page : Wordpress Documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_dashboard_page)

Comment: Great advice, I suppose I can track down where the hook is that creates the account and make it so it asks before creating. Thanks Edgar!

Comment: There are the user meta too, it could help you a lot. You can point some meta to see the ability to buy or not, something like this.

Comment: Okay, so the user meta is the data the user inputs on the form before sending it. Then the meta gets sent to an email address or wp dashboard to wait for confirmation of ability to purchase. Also, I'm going to make it so you only have to ask once at the beginning of the customers registration. Thanks again man!